# Why does my opponent keep driving into a wall?

Tags: mario-kart-ds

I was trying to play multiplayer Mario Kart with my sister for our DS's on a long trip and little did she know I had cheats enabled.  When the race started everything seemed fine until a little bit later when my sister said she was in first.  I thought she was kidding because I was in first on my DS and she was in 8th place, yet on her DS it said she was in first place and I was in 8th.

As looked around the track to find out where she was, I saw her ramming into a wall and turning in circles.  That is what confused me.  Why does using cheats cause your multiplayer opponents to freak out into walls?  What I mainly want to know is if there is any way to stop this from happening and why it happens as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Whatever you are doing *probably* causes your DS to lose a connection to hers, so her kart just does whatever it last was doing with nobody to command it further, and on her side you are doing the same thing. Nintendo probably thought of there being a bit of a cheating problem and remedied it this way.

Comment: I have changed the question to be more clear now.

Comment: Motion to reopen the question now that it's edited to be clear.

Comment: Also, Ethan, stop trying to cheat against your sister in Mario Kart.

Comment: I just had to vote that comment up as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have the source code available of course, but generally speaking this sort of thing is called a desync.

These games are just running through game logic. When playing multiplayer, usually the games assume the game logic is in sync between all participants - so if something happens due to an event for one participant, it's also happening in the same way for all other participants.

Cheats can mess with that. If your DS is handling something differently than your sister's - say, a kart's top speed or acceleration is faster for you - and the network code doesn't account for that or attempt to correct, then you will very quickly get out of sync. On your game, you totally made that turn perfectly, while on her game you turned early and crashed into a pipe.

Desyncs are a major source of bugs in game development. Even without accounting for someone hacking in cheats, ensuring perfect synchronization can be hard for a complex title. Even things like framerate, network speed, and poorly-coded random number usage can potentially cause issues if you're not careful.

In order to not make this happen, be sure both games are running the same thing - so either use hacked-in cheats on both games, or neither. No guarantees that the cheats themselves are stable, though, so not using them at all is probably best. I know from personal experience that Mario Kart DS plays great with multiple people if you don't mess around with it first.